# How to pin the bottom of a VStack to the bottom of a ScrollView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Pin `VStack` to the bottom of its parent `ScrollView`

I have a `ScrollView` containing a `VStack` with some `Text`. I want the bottom of this `VStack` to be "pinned" to the bottom of the `ScrollView`.

In the image below, I want the `VStack` with a yellow background to extend all the way below. It's not pinned to the bottom of the green ScrollView.

[image]

The `ScrollView is wrapped in a` GeometryReader` and the screen's height is passed to the nested VStack. From what I can see, this measured height does not include the bottom part of the screen.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gm in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Title")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .padding(.leading)

                        Spacer()
                    }

                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 60)

                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text("Header Text")
                    }
                    .frame(height: 60)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(6.5)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 60)

                    // I want this to occupy all the remaining space
                    VStack {
                        Text("ABC")

                        Text("DEF")
                    }
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(height: gm.size.height)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.green.ignoresSafeArea())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add `.ignoresSafeArea(edges: [.bottom])` after completing brackets of `GeometryReader`.